# How do I set a varnish response TTL dynamically?

Tags: cache, varnish, ttl

my php script is sending a header `X_Cache_ttl: 1h` and in my varnish config file I have

```
sub vcl_fetch
{
    if(beresp.http.X-Cache-ttl){
            set beresp.ttl = beresp.http.X-Cache-ttl;
    }
}
```

but the line with the set command is causing varnish to fail when I try to start it.

in the log I get

```
Expression has type STRING, expected DURATION
('input' Line 116 Pos 34) -- ('input' Line 116 Pos 56)
            set beresp.ttl = beresp.http.X-Cache-ttl;
```

How do I convert `X-Cache-ttl` to a duration so that I can dynamically set the TTL?

I would like to avoid multiple if statements similar to

```
if(beresp.http.X-Cache-ttl == "60s") {
    set beresp.ttl = 60s;
}

if(beresp.http.X-Cache-ttl == "1h") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1h;
}
```

If it matters I'm using varnish 3.0.3 on centos 6.

Comment: I encountered same roadblock. Did you find any work-around for varnish 3.x or even 2.1.5 for that matter?  At the moment, I have 2.1.5 on production and 3.x on a staging. Cannot move to ver 4.x because it's syntax is vastly different and our VCL is a bit complicated to move to new version immediately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`vmod_std`](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_std.html) module has a function that should do what you're looking for.

`import std;` at the top of the VCL, then this should work:

```
sub vcl_fetch
{
    set beresp.ttl = std.duration(beresp.http.X-Cache-ttl, 1h);
}
```

..where the `1h` is your default if the header isn't set.

Comment: If you're running Varnish 4, `vcl 4.0;` must be at the top of VCL file, and then `import std;`

Answer (score 2):

According to the Varnish documentation you can use the `Cache-Control` header.

> **Cache-Control**
>
> The 'Cache-Control' header instructs caches how to handle the content.
>   Varnish cares about the max-age parameter and uses it to calculate the
>   TTL for an object.
>
> So make sure you issue a 'Cache-Control' header with a max-age header.
>   You can have a look at what Varnish Software's Drupal server issues:

```
$ GET -Used http://www.varnish-software.com/|grep ^Cache-Control
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
```

https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/doc/sphinx/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.rst